# Why can't i use DataAnnotations KeyAttribute for composite keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EntityFramework Core restricts using KeyAttribute for defining composite keys.
But what is the reason for this limitation? I [have found a solution](https://github.com/Sellec/efCoreCompositeKey) for this without using Fluent api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11003) it is in the backlog to be implemented in the upcoming version of EF Core. And from this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10111), here is the explanation that you were looking for:

> The reason is that it used a combination of Key and Column for ordering, but column ordering is not the same thing as key ordering, and so this caused confusion and issues in EF6. Changing existing data annotations is also costly because of their relationship to .NET Core and .NET Framework.
>
> However, we see the value in being able to this and other common configuration using attributes, since the jump to the fluent API can be a big one. Therefore, we will investigate creating a new library/package with additional new EF configuration attributes that can be used alongside data annotations. This would be one of the things that would be implemented there.

However, [According to this announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/features#ef-63-on-net-core), from **ASP.NET Core 3.0** you can use all the features of EF 6.x with ASP.NET Core as there will be **EF 6.3 on .NET Core >= 3.0**

Comment: Btw, "backlog" means it's "tracked", but not scheduled for implementation, so it might never be addressed :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, until EF 6.3 and Core 3.0 would be released and for EF 6.2/Core 2.0 compability, can founded solution be used as is?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use `Fluent API` with `IEntityTypeConfiguration` like : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#self-contained-type-configuration-for-code-first. This is will give complete separation of concern.

Comment: @IvanStoev They did not close the issue that means there is a slight chance of implementing this in distant future :)